# Darken background image using tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to make the background darker so thats it subtle. The background image is dynamic otherwise I would edit just the image. I cannot for the life of me find a way to make it darker without impacting all the child divs

```
<ul role="list" class="mr-6 grid w-full grid-cols-1 gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3">
  <li v-for="user in all_users.data" :key="user.id" class="col-span-1 flex flex-col divide-y divide-gray-700 rounded-lg bg-gray-900 text-center subpixel-antialiased shadow-xl">
    <div class="rounded-t-lg bg-cover" style="background-image: url(https://64.media.tumblr.com/3568a4257d3ca1875783c58cb0e7e3ab/c5e61c99103a6e47-3b/s1280x1920/5953636dd2d1f46521b2cbb33b4e5cd5d978d8c9.jpg)">
      <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col p-8">
        <img v-if="user.profile_photo_path === null" class="mx-auto h-32 w-32 flex-shrink-0 rounded-full border-4 border-red-800" src="https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/03/49/49/79/1000_F_349497933_Ly4im8BDmHLaLzgyKg2f2yZOvJjBtlw5.jpg" alt="" />
        <h3 v-if="user.user_display_name === null" class="text-md mt-6 font-medium text-gray-100"></h3>
        <h3 class="text-md mt-6 font-medium text-gray-100">{{ user.user_display_name }}</h3>
        <h4 class="mt-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-100">@{{ user.name }}</h4>
        <dl class="mt-1 flex flex-grow flex-col justify-between">
          <dt class="sr-only">Location</dt>
          <dd class="text-sm text-gray-300">{{ user.user_city }}, {{ user.user_country }}</dd>
          <dt class="sr-only">Is Online</dt>
          <dd class="mt-3">
            <span class="rounded-full bg-green-700 px-2 py-1 text-xs font-medium text-white">Online</span>
          </dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="-mt-px flex divide-x divide-gray-700">
        <div class="flex w-0 flex-1">
          <a href="#" class="relative -mr-px inline-flex w-0 flex-1 items-center justify-center rounded-bl-lg border border-transparent py-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-red-800 hover:text-gray-100">
            <MailIcon class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-100" aria-hidden="true" />
            <span class="ml-3 text-gray-200">Message</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="-ml-px flex w-0 flex-1">
          <a href="#" class="relative inline-flex w-0 flex-1 items-center justify-center rounded-br-lg border border-transparent py-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-red-800 hover:text-gray-500">
            <UserAddIcon class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-100" aria-hidden="true" />
            <span class="ml-3 text-gray-200">Follow</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be really well appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to modify how you do the background image. The Top few lines SHOULD be...

```
  <li v-for="user in all_users.data" :key="user.id" class="col-span-1 flex flex-col divide-y divide-gray-700 rounded-lg bg-gray-900 text-center subpixel-antialiased shadow-xl">
    <div class="relative overflow-hidden rounded-t-lg">
      <img v-if="user.cover_photo_path === null" class="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full object-cover " src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/3568a4257d3ca1875783c58cb0e7e3ab/c5e61c99103a6e47-3b/s1280x1920/5953636dd2d1f46521b2cbb33b4e5cd5d978d8c9.jpg" alt="" />
      <img v-else class="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full object-cover " :src="user.cover_photo_path" alt="" />
      <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-black/60"></div>
      <div class="relative flex flex-1 flex-col p-8">
```

We are using an absolute and inset then setting the bg-black with the percentage required.